# Is there a way to reset or clear a serial "port in use" condition?

Tags: java, debugging

I'm adding some debug code to a program that prints trace data to a serial port. After printing some data, the serial port gets a condition of "PortInUseException". In order to continue my debugging, I need to write to the serial port. I know that the port is not being used by the software I'm debugging, but might, for some reason unknown to me, confiscates the port even though I have it open myself. Is there any way to reset the port so that I can use it again?

Comment: What operating system?  Which implementation of the Communications API?  Can you show some code?

Comment: Why not investigate the reason why it says "PortInUseException" ?

Comment: Are you using JavaComm or RXTX?